# How to redirect dynamic URLs within a directory to a new directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I had a knowledge base software program installed on my site located in /kb/

I have installed a new program located in /tech/knowledgebase/

All of the URLs generated by the old program are dynamic and look like:

kb/questions/846/2014+Corvette%3A+GM+TechLink+Article%3A+Heated+Seat+May+Turn+Off

and another example:

kb/questions/841/2014+Corvette%3A+GM+TechLink+Article%3A+Blank+Touch+Screen+after+Start-up+and+in+Reverse

I want to use .htaccess to permanently redirect all of these dynamic links to just /tech/knowledgebase/index.php

I've tried several different redirects within .htaccess, but nothing seems to work.  It rewrites part of the path, but can't seem to handle the keywords spilled into part of the url.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Please post the redirects you have tried.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/kb/(.*)$ /tech/knolwedgebase/ [L,R=301]

Comment: RewriteRule ^/kb/$ /tech/knowledgebase/ [R=301,L]

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^kb(/.*)?$ /tech/knolwedgebase/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: That worked!  Thank you!!